# Reflect to test if a value is a string

Tags: go, reflection

I'm trying to test if a value coming from the gjson library is a string in the quickest and simplest way possible. I don't want to use a switch type assertion.

```
if reflect.TypeOf(gjson.Get(input, "name").Value()) != "string" {
    return "Not a string!"  
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gjson.Get` returns a [`Result`](https://godoc.org/github.com/tidwall/gjson#Result), so you can simply check its `Type` field:

```
if gjson.Get(input, "name").Type != gjson.String {
    return "Not a string!"  
}
```

Comment: Hey im trying to do the same for Null now, and its not working. Is not workign with nil either.

Comment: @MatiasBarrios: You need to compare `Result.Type` with `gjson.Null`. It's possible, however, that what you believe is `null` might be some other value. Print the entire object to confirm.

Comment: you were right. It was a string with the literal text "null"